# Editing multiple layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, editing

I'm wondering how to edit multiple layers, maybe standalone.

I have 2 shapefiles.
1 line and
1 point

What i want is the following:
When i select a line, then the line and the point shape has to go in de edit mode. The selected line changes from color (say red to blue). Now i want to insert serveral new points on the line, wich gets a id number from the line shape.

I think this is possible with some py code, but i can figure out how.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the line being edited in your example. First, use "settingss > snapping options" to make sure that you snap the line when you draw a new point. Once you have added all your points, you can use "vector > data management tools > join attributes by location" to extract all the line ID for each point.

Comment: When 1 select a line  i has to go in the edit mode and also the point shape. Once i add a point on the line the point has to be saved directly with the line id. It has to be very use friendly because iets a field solution. And when finished in the line shape there will the some new info added like user,time